# Run Brave Browser in a sandbox/VM on an M2-Mac running Sonoma 14.3?

Tags: virtualization, sandbox

I need to run Brave on my Mac Sonoma 14.3 (M2 Mac). Unfortunately, it is a managed device and I cannot install Brave directly. I may, anyhow, virtualise it.

Installing a full-fledged OS in a Parallels-VM just to run Brave seems a little over the top for me though. I was hoping for a more Docker-like approach that would allow me to install and run Brave in a sandbox.

Is there something like this or is Parallels the only viable approach?

Comment: If you can’t install/run a different browser due to MDM limitations, how are you going to install VM or Docker (and similar) apps?  We’ll need a clearer picture of what can be run on your Mac.

Comment: You should ask the entity (employer? school?) which manages the device to allow the Brave browser to be installed.